# Cambiar orden de aplicacion de los filtros where en una consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2016

He intentado modificar en el que se aplican los where en una SQL y no he sido capaz.
Al final he conseguido hacer un workaround por lo cual no me ha hecho falta ser capaz de ordenar la ejecución de un where, pero me he quedado con la duda.

El problema lo tenía al castear un valor String a int.

```
select * 
from tabla1
where texto1 = 'DATO' 
      and numerico1 = cast(texto2 as int)
```

En este caso, todos los valores de "texto2" si se aplica el filtro de `texto1 = 'DATO'` son todos como los siguientes:

```
123, 1234, 5212, 1234, etc...
```

El problema viene que si el filtro `texto1 = 'DATO'` no se aplica puede haber casos que sean así:

```
123|3412, 1234|4213, 452|21314, etc...
```

El workaround que he hecho ha sido castear el numero a texto y luego compararlo:

```
select * 
from tabla1
where texto1 = 'DATO' 
      and cast(numerico1 as varchar) = texto2
```

Como solución para mi caso en particular me funciona, pero querría saber si es posible modificar el orden en el que se aplican los filtros del WHERE en una consulta SQL

EDICION

**Ejemplo OK**:

```
select campo_que_queremos
from tabla
where filtro1 = 'GT55GHR'
    and filtro2 = 'FOTO.jpg' 
    and numerico1 = cast(1232585 as int) 
order by gdmoseqn desc
```

En este caso nos devuelve lo que buscamos porque el valor que intentamos convertir a entero es: 1232585

**Ejemplo ERROR**:

```
select campo_que_queremos
from tabla
where filtro1 = 'GT55GHR' 
    and filtro2 = 'FOTO.jpg' 
    and numerico1 = cast('1232585|14283'as int) 
order by gdmoseqn desc
```

En este caso SQL nos devuelve el siguiente error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: En el WHERE se evalúan, para cada registro, una serie de condiciones lógicas. No termino de entender a qué te refieres con el orden. Se cumplen o no, ¿en qué influye el orden? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo para entender a qué te refieres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cualquier solución que recibas, será algo que no pueda utilizar índices y por lo tanto se volverán lentas eventualmente.

Lo mejor sería rediseñar esas tablas para eliminar el diseño EAV (Entidad-Atributo-Valor) y tener una tabla normalizada.

El órden en el WHERE no se puede controlar, pero podrías intentar otras opciones:

```
--1
SELECT * 
FROM tabla1
WHERE texto1 = 'DATO' 
AND numerico1 = TRY_CAST(texto2 as int);

--2
SELECT * 
FROM tabla1
WHERE CASE WHEN texto1 = 'DATO' 
            THEN CASE WHEN numerico1 = TRY_CAST(texto2 as int) 
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                 END
       END = 1;
```

Comment: El rediseñar las tablas es algo inviable, utilizamos un ERP y esa es una de las tablas estandar. Respecto a la solución que propones me parece perfecta, aunque como comentas respecto al rediseño de las tablas disminuirá el rendimiento con el tiempo.